# SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qtcore

I am trying to plot something with matplotlib but when I import it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

in Pycharm Community 2016.1.4 using Anaconda version 3.5.1, I get this error:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception
```

What is wrong here? I havent found anything via google or here on SO that is the same as my problem.

Comment: What is the full error you get, including traceback? Can you try `from PyQt4 import QtCore` without importing matplotlib and will it give the same error?

Comment: I am having the same issue @user3813234
Ever figure out a fix? 
When i try `from PyQt5 import QtCore` in PyCharm, I receive the following error:
`/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/me/pyfo/project/testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/pyfo/project/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception

Process finished with exit code 1
`

Comment: @gmonz Not really, I ended up re-installing Python and PyQt - and lo and behold, it worked. Not very satisfactory, but thats how I solved it.

Comment: interesting, I did the same thing. How did you install? Homebrew or download from site? I hear some of these issues will be fixed in May with the new release of PyQt5 5.9

Try running this script if you have PyQt5.8:  https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-menu/
Here is my error: http://pastebin.com/RJ3gnrAT

Does it work for you @user3813234 ?

Comment: For those coming here because they get the `SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception` error despite that pyqt is installed. Check your version. I had version 5.9.2. Upgrading to 5.15 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

I would Suggest you do these things it will definitely work as it worked for me.

```
python -m pip install PyQt5
```

This will completely resolve this issue by re-installing it with all dependencies required.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this issue with :

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyqt
```